# string.isalpha() returning False under custom django validator whether string contains a number or not

Tags: python, django, django-validation

I am trying to use custom validation on a Django CharField model field. I'm checking whether the name has number in it. If it does, raise a `ValidationError`. I use the line `if name.isalpha() is False: raise ValidationError`. For some reason this equates to False whether there is a number present in the string or not. I checked to make sure that `name` was the value I was expecting it to be and that it was indeed a string. Here is my code:

> models.py

```
name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_name], max_length=100, default='', unique=True)
```

> validation.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


def validate_name(name):
    print(name.isalpha())

    if name.isalpha is False:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('Name can only contain letters A-Z. Not numbers.'),
            params={'name': name},
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
if name.isalpha() is False:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('Name can only contain letters A-Z. Not numbers.'),
            params={'name': name},
        )
```

Besides you could use the RegexValidator to save some lines of code

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

letters_only = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z ]*$', _('Only letters are allowed.'))
```